# Calling a POST variable in PHP-function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I have a PHP-file with multiple php functions in it.
I am sending a Javascript Variable with an AJAX-call, POST method to that PHP-file.`

Now the variable IS accessible in my PHP-file but not in that specific function where I want it...

```
$("#dropdown").change(function () {
    var value = $("#dropdown").val();
    console.log(value);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'text', 
        url: "PhpFunctions.php",
        data: {id:$("#dropdown").val()},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

                    $("div.geselecteerdVliegtuig").fadeIn("slow", function () {
                        console.log("Vliegtuigdetail faded in");
                    });
                    /*
                    $("div.vliegtuigenEnabled2").hide();
                    console.log("vliegtuigEnabled ID's hidden");
                    */
                },

        error: function (err) {
            alert('error: ' + err);
        }
    }); //END AJAX CALL`



//I CAN ACCESS DATABASE AND ID IS ACCESSIBLE HERE
//Connect to server
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());

//Connect to database
$select_db = mysql_select_db("Luchthaven") or die("Could not find database");

$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id; //WORKS

//NEED TO ACCESS IS HERE
function GeselecteerdVliegtuig() {
makeConnection();

//Query the database
$id = $_POST['id'];

//$query = "SELECT * FROM vliegtuig WHERE vliegtuig_ID = 'PEG431';";
//echo "SELECT * FROM vliegtuig WHERE vliegtuig_ID = 'PEG431';<br/>";

$query = "SELECT * FROM vliegtuig WHERE vliegtuig_ID = '" . $id . "';";
echo "SELECT * FROM vliegtuig WHERE vliegtuig_ID = '" . $id . "';<br/>";

$fetch = mysql_query($query) or die("could not fetch data");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)) {
    echo "<tr id=" . $row['vliegtuig_ID'] . ">";
    echo "<td>" . $row['vliegtuig_ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['maatschappij'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lengte'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['breedte'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['kilometerstand'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['bouwjaar'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['bereik'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['aantalMotoren'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
} // END WHILE

mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
echo "<b>Connection closed<b><br/><br/>";
```

}

Comment: Add the argument to your function `function GeselecteerdVliegtuig($id) {<code>}`

Comment: You don't even call `GeselecteerdVliegtuig()` function. How is it executed?

Comment: In my html a have a <?php GeselecteerdVliegtuig() ?>

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I've collected some of the ones I use more commonly in this [GitHub project](https://github.com/tadman/escape.fail/tree/gh-pages/snippets).

Comment: @tadman Thank you so much - they're super useful. In case you find it useful I've uploaded [a bookmark-bar javascript for inserting these messages](http://pastebin.com/BKfMUur6). It's not that it's difficult code (it's really just simple jQuery), but I use it quite a lot. It opens up the comment field on SO, and pastes the text.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Nice trick, and thanks for carrying on the good fight. It might seem like a pointless battle, but I've seen a real shift in how people approach database problems. Every bit helps.

Comment: @tadman A single person switching from their bad habits rather than "urh, doesn't matter, it's just internal and I'll fix it later" is a huge win in my opinion. If there's just one more person to have SQL injection knowledge that they can teach others, or even just fix their own code, it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the $_POST['id'] variable to that function GeselecteerdVliegtuig($id) and call the function with GeselecteerdVliegtuig($_POST['id'])

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this line:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

as you might want to use your functionality even if your value is not located in your `$_POST["id"]`. Modify your function header from

```
function GeselecteerdVliegtuig() {
```

to

```
function GeselecteerdVliegtuig($id) {
```

Call your function this way:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    GeselecteerdVliegtuig($_POST['id']);
}
```

and call your function from the page where you posted the value, make sure that the page where you posted exists, works and responds.

Finally, when everything is working change the way you are working with the database, because your current approach has a security leak due to SQL injection possibilities. What if I visit your page and execute the following in the console:

```
$("#dropdown").val("0'; delete from vliegtuig where '' = '");
```

and then trigger the post? It will remove every single record from your table unless you are making sure that these attempts fail.